# How to use PDFView in cocoa app?

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode4, pdfview

I am working on cocoa now a days so, little bit new to mac development.
I want to open a PDF from my server. Is this possible with `PDFView`?
If anyone guide me in this then it will be very helpful for me.
Is there any sample code to open a PDF file in PDFView ?

Thanks in advance..!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got answer..

at least working for me..  :)

```
NSString *urlStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1.pdf" ofType:nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlStr];
PDFDocument *pdfDoc = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithURL:url];
[pdfView setDocument:pdfDoc];
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift version (do not forget to import Quartz module)

```
    guard let docPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("1", ofType: "pdf") else { return }

    let docURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(docPath)
    let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(URL: docURL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3.0 version:)

```
    guard let docPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "1", ofType: "pdf") else { return }

    let docURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: docPath)
    let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: docURL)
    uxPdf.document = pdfDocument
```